# Objective C: Zooming UIScrollView Properly

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview

I am having issues with my scrollview whenever i zoom the view.
When i zoom the view it is automatically positioned on the upper left corner. What i want to do is the view to stay where it is positioned once it is moved.

Here's my code:

```
    mainSV = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024)];
    [mainSV setPagingEnabled:YES];
    [mainSV setDelegate:self];
    [mainSV setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];
    [mainSV setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
    [mainSV setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [mainSV setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [mainSV setMaximumZoomScale:2.0];
    [mainSV setMinimumZoomScale:1.0];
    [mainSV setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];
    [mainSV setClipsToBounds:YES];
    [mainSV setContentSize:CGSizeMake(768, 1024)];
    [self.view addSubview:mainSV];

    innerSV = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024)];
    [innerSV setPagingEnabled:YES];
    [innerSV setDelegate:self];
    [innerSV setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];
    [innerSV setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
    [innerSV setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [innerSV setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [innerSV setClipsToBounds:YES];
    [innerSV setContentSize:CGSizeMake(768*numOfPages, 1024)];
    [mainSV addSubview:innerSV];

- (UIView*)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView {

    return innerSV;
}
```

InnerSV is also a `UIScrollView` that holds all the images in my app.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is created by the `innerSV` scrollview paging. 
Set it to FALSE and it should work.

Cheers!

Comment: FALSE works for me 
"no" made some problems
Thank you very much